# How to check whether an array list contains a object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have added several mail id's to $scope.MultiEmailsList,then i have assigned single email to $scope.SingleEmail.Now i want to check $scope.SingleEmail with $scope.MultiEmailsList list.

```
if ($scope.MultiEmailsList.contains($scope.SingleEmail))
 {
    console.log("Mail Id Already Exists");
 }
else
  {
     console.log("Mail Id Not Exists");            
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a very simple function like this:

```
function existsInArray( arr, item ) {

    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) 
        if( arr[ i ] === item ) return true;

    return false; 

}
```

Or use `Underscore.js` inbuilt: `_.indexOf( arr, item );` function. :)

Comment: for(var i=0;i<$scope.Email.length;i++)
                {
                    if($scope.Email[i]===$scope.user.Email)
                    {
                        console.log("Mail Id Alresdy Exists");
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

It will be solve your problem:

```
if ($scope.Email.indexOf($scope.user.Email) !== -1)
            {
                console.log("Mail Id Already Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'index.php/Welcome/Signup',
                    data: $scope.user,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencode'}
                }).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.Enquiry = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    $location.path('/EnquiryResponse');
                });
            }
```

Comment: i have faced this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: Use `$scope.Email.indexOf`

Comment: Where i need to use $scope.Email.indexOf

Comment: This isn't supported on all browsers though.

Comment: let me know which browser is support this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.MultiEmailsList = ["nitin@gmail.com","test@gmail.com"];
$scope.SingleEmail = "nitin@gmail.com";


if(($scope.MultiEmailsList).indexOf($scope.SingleEmail)!= -1){
    console.log("value exists");
}else{
   console.log("value not exists");
}
```

please check this might help you..